# org :PROPERTY: "read only" and "no spell check"?

Tags: org-mode

I have a very long document inside one org file, I plan to add more documents to it making many top level headers in it.

I was wondering if there is a way to set a property to an org section making it and it's sub-sections read only, and avoid flyspell check the spelling too.

I read [The Kitchin Research Group: Make some org-sections read-only](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/09/13/Make-some-org-sections-read-only/) for the read only part, but I'm not sure if that way covers the all sub-sections too.

Comment: You have two questions in one -- I'd suggest separating it into two -- one for read only and one for skip flyspell and/or ispell.

Comment: Somehow off-topic, but wouldn't it be convenient to have all top-level sections in separate files, and then `#include` all into a main org file? You can use org-occur for searching several files at once, and you avoid messing with already revised sections.